# Split list into columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'], 
                    'Values': [['AB', 'BC'], np.NaN, ['AB', 'CD']]}))

df

    ID  Values
0   ID1 [AB, BC]
1   ID2   NaN
2   ID3 [AB, CD]
```

I want to split the item inside list into column such that

```
    ID  AB  BC  CD
0   ID1 1   1   0
1   ID2 0   0   0
2   ID3 1   0   1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas functions working with missing values nice, so use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) with [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is for extract column and last `join` to original data:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('Values').str.join('|').str.get_dummies())
print (df)
    ID  AB  BC  CD
0  ID1   1   1   0
1  ID2   0   0   0
2  ID3   1   0   1
```

EDIT: If values are not lists, only string representation of lists use `ast.literal_eval` for converting to lists:

```
import ast

df = (df.join(df.pop('Values')
        .apply(ast.literal_eval)
        .str.join('|')
        .str.get_dummies()))
```

Comment: with Pop, it's not popping values but individual character

Comment: @Hardikgupta - For me working nice, in real data are lists?

Comment: my real data is like ['ABC', 'PWR']